# How do I find the answer to this differential graph?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

This isn't very advanced calculus, but I've been having trouble and can't figure out where to start on this problem. How do I proceed?

[image: Graph of g']

Comment: I embedded that image for you. Now, the thing is, there are several parts here. Where are you stuck? Which parts are giving you trouble? Have you at least tried all of them, even if you don't have the earlier parts?

Comment: Well, the first one is pretty easy, you literally have just interpret the value of the graph at $x=0$. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: I've given most of the problem a try. I've worked backwards on those other two (C & D), but couldn't find a specific answer. I just kept getting the same fraction as I got before when i tried testing it out with each other. I apologize if this seems way too obvious to be asking on here. But some simple things like this I get stuck on. The specific issue that I face is the fact that there is no specific equation to the graph. If I'm just given the first part (a) g'(0) and (b) without anything else besides the graph to work on, where would I start to figure out the rest of it?

Comment: try to include your attempt in the post itself and not in the comment. Also, really include the working rather than just a description.

Comment: The derivative tells us the rate at which the function is changing.  If $g' > 0$ in an interval, the function is increasing; if $g' < 0$ in an interval, the function is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to try to find out an equation for the graph, or for the original function $g$. These are generally qualitative questions.

For (a) and (b), it's just a question of reading the graph you're given. We wish to find two specific values of $g'$, given the graph of $g'$, and we do so by reading them off.

For (c) and (d), ignore the graph - the values we're given for the derivative are what matters here. What does the derivative of a function $g$ at a point tell you about the graph of that function near that point?